# Docker Container - Oracle Database deadlock

Tags: oracle, docker, containers, deadlock

I have a .Net Core 3.1 api that uses Dapper to call a stored procedure in a Oracle Database. Everything works fine locally, but when the app is deployed in a docker container, it never responds even when the stored procedure has end all his tasks.

Stored procedure takes around 20 minutes to finish when it is executed from oracle developer.

Api is deployed in a windows server docker engine.

Docker log is not showing any usefull data.

**I already tried:**

1. Running it on IIS, works great
2. Deploying it on a docker container and calling the stored procedure with Oracle ODP instead of dapper, did not worked.
3. Call it sync instead of async, deployed in container, did not worked.

Do you have any clue of what is happening?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: That's not a deadlock.  Oracle will detect a  deadlock.  Look  in the oracle alert logs

Comment: Did you try isolating the problem by building a minimal app, e.g. without dapper and with a simple stored procedure? If your call throws an exception, why don't you see it? Maybe an Oracle connection issue?

Comment: Thanks for your respond @OldProgrammer, the alert log shows 

TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 505
 
TNS-00505: Operation timed out
    nt secondary err code: 145
    nt OS err code: 0
  Client address: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<my address>)(PORT=<port assigned by docker desktop>))

Comment: Hi @Piper, thats exaclty what i tried with oracle ODP, a simple call to the stored procedure deployed in docker container. Derived from the problem insolation it seems that container-oracle database relation is the problem source.